# Emptying Vue.js Array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I recently started using Vue.js, and have ran into a small problem. I have an array, and have used Vue.js to add that array into the rendered code. Using standard `.push` works fine for that.

However, I also want to be able to clear the array which would clear the rendered code. But when I try `array = []` to clear it, the code doesn't work, and everything stops working.

How do I clear the list without breaking the program?

I replicated the problem in the below snippet.

```js
let results = [1, 2];
let num = 3;

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        results: results
    }
});

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
  results.push(num);
  num++;
});

document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", function() {
  results = [];
  num = 1;
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>

<div id="app">
  <h1 v-for="result in results"> {{ result }}</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Move the buttons inside your #app and use Vue's [v-on:click](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) handler.

```js
let results = [1, 2];
let num = 3;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    results: results
  },
  methods: {
    add: function() {
      this.results.push(num);
      num++;
    },
    clear: function() {
      this.results = [];
      num = 1;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="add">Add</button>
  <button v-on:click="clear">Clear</button>
  <h1 v-for="result in results"> {{ result }}</h1>
</div>
```

---

**Solution2:**
Use Vue's [$data API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-data)

```js
let results = [1, 2];
let num = 3;

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        results: results
    }
});

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
  app.$data.results.push(num)
  num++;
});

document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", function() {
  app.$data.results = [];
  num = 1;
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>

<div id="app">
  <h1 v-for="result in results"> {{ result }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Your second solution is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

So there are a couple of small things that I updated in your app to be done *the vue way*, as opposed to the old vanilla JS approach.

- First off we manage all component data within the `data` section, so you don't need your above JS variables.
- It's also a good approach to return a function that returns your json here, rather than just have your json object raw.
- Next, you no longer need to use that old-school `document.getElementById("add").addEventListener` approach, instead just return your functions in the `methods`, and then simply call to them with the `v-on:click="addNew"` attribute

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => {
    return {
   results: [3, 1, 4, 1, 5]
    };
  },
  methods: {
      addNew() {
      const nextNum = this.$data.results.length + 1;
      this.$data.results.push(nextNum);
    },
    clearAll(){
      this.$data.results = [];
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Awesome Counting App</h2>
  <button v-on:click="addNew">Add</button>
  <button v-on:click="clearAll">Clear</button>
  <hr>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="result in results" v-bind:key="result">
      {{result}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation as well

Comment: Sure, just writing it now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Make it more Vue ish!

```
<button @click="add">Add</button>
<button @click="clear">Clear</button>

var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        results: [1, 2],
        num : 3
      }, 
      methods(){
          add(){
            this.results.push(num);
            this.num++;
          },
          clear(){
           this.results = [];
           this.num = 1;
          }
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you working with Vuejs you don't need of declare any variable out Vue instance, and any vanilla code outside them.

You can use vanilla inside vue instance, but for now, you dont need it:

```
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
  results.push(num);
  num++;
});

document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", function() {
  results = [];
  num = 1;
});
```

Instead you may use like this:

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    results: [],
    num: 1
},
methods: {
    addNumberArray(){
    this.results.push(number);
    number++;
  },
  clearNumberArray(){
    this.results = [];
    number = 1;
  }
}
});
```

Here a live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/n4krde0h/19/